# printf("%.0f\n", nc) did not print intented info

Tags: c

I am following instructions to write a program of characters counting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    double nc;

    for (nc=0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc);
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

After it was compiled and run,

```
$ ./a.out
ff
fdg
fd


fdr
```

It did not print the counting.
What's the problem with my code?

Comment: Why are you using `double` for an `int` (or `size_t`) count? E.g. `size_t nc; for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; nc++) {}; printf ("%zu\n", nc);`?

Comment: How does your input stream end?

Comment: You have a semicolon after the `for` loop, so the `printf` won't execute until the loop ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you never enter `EOF`.

Use <kbd>Control+Z</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Control+D</kbd> on UNIX/Linux/OSX to get `EOF`.

Comment: But see: [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That might have been true for some version of Windows 10 ... I only can tell you that it works without putting the console into legacy mode in 10.0.18252.1000.

Comment: Business is still stuck on 1703 (and missed out on the latest 1809 disappearing documents, intel sound driver problems, blue-screening HP boxes). I haven't tested beyond 1703, but could confirm that with either 1607 or 1703, legacy mode was needed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "disappearing documents" sounds scary O.O

Comment: Oh boy! [Microsoft deletes deleterious file deletion bug from Windows 10 October 2018 Update](http://go.reg.cx/tdml/dfd67/5be770ff/ba67ad4e/2Q4y)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Always knew that undeterministic cleanup is just asking for trouble ;)